# upload multiple images in sql database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for a way to upload multiple images (drag and drop) at the same time in an sql database. I have searched all over the internet but couldnt find something good (like select more than one image and upload). Can u give me any good solution?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Do you mean to save multiple binary image in SQL database?

Comment: i want to select multiple images at the same time and upload them to sql database.

Comment: You need to give more details. Do you want to use a JavaScript uploader to do this? Do you want a basic [Browse] button that can select several files? How do you want it to function? So many ways you can do this.